Custom generic enum converter for mongodb in java
I have a lot of enums stored in legacy way (kebab-case) in mongodb. But all enums are stored in java code as SCREAMING_SNAKE_CASE. I create a new micro-service, and it uses spring-data-mongodb and it will use all collections where enums stored in that way. I can't break backward compatibility, so I have to read and write them as kebab-case. Is it possible to create a generic converter for enums (for example, annotated with @KebabCaseStore) that will save such classes in proper way without writing custom read/write converter for every enum?

At least one way would be to use an AttributeConverter<E, String>.

@JoopEggen but the question is not about JPA, it's about mongodb

sorry, I thought of https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/reference/mongodb/mapping/custom-conversions.html

Well, actually it works) But the problem is that I have 30+ enums, and have to write custom converters for each of them. I would prefer to write one with enum as generic, but I just don't know how to properly write generic parameters so mongodb driver understands what I want from it

An EnumConverter should be feasible using values to convert case.

Well, that what I've finally done.
@ReadingConverter
class StringToEnumReaderConverterFactory(
    enums: Collection<Class<out Enum<*>>>
) : ConditionalGenericConverter {

    private val enumClassToItsConstants: Map<Class<out Enum<*>>, Map<String, Enum<*>>> =
        enums.associateWith { it.enumConstants.associateBy { enumConstant -> enumConstant.name } }

    override fun getConvertibleTypes(): MutableSet<GenericConverter.ConvertiblePair> {
        return enumClassToItsConstants.keys.map { enumClass ->
            GenericConverter.ConvertiblePair(
                String::class.java,
                enumClass
            )
        }
            .toMutableSet()
    }

    override fun convert(source: Any?, sourceType: TypeDescriptor, targetType: TypeDescriptor): Any? {
        val s: String = source?.let { it as String }
            ?.uppercase()
            ?.replace("-", "_")
            ?: return null
        val constants = enumClassToItsConstants[targetType.objectType]
        return constants?.get(s)
    }

    override fun matches(sourceType: TypeDescriptor, targetType: TypeDescriptor): Boolean {
        return enumClassToItsConstants.containsKey(targetType.objectType)
    }
}

@WritingConverter
class EnumToStringWritingConverterFactory(
    enums: Collection<Class<out Enum<*>>>
) : ConditionalGenericConverter {
    private val enums = enums.toSet()

    override fun getConvertibleTypes(): MutableSet<GenericConverter.ConvertiblePair> {
        return enums.map { GenericConverter.ConvertiblePair(it, String::class.java) }.toMutableSet()
    }

    override fun convert(source: Any?, sourceType: TypeDescriptor, targetType: TypeDescriptor): Any {
        val enum = source as Enum<*>
        return enum.name.lowercase().replace("_", "-")
    }

    override fun matches(sourceType: TypeDescriptor, targetType: TypeDescriptor): Boolean {
        return sourceType.objectType in enums
    }
}


Good work, and thanks for sharing. Many people do not like using capital enum constants in data.
